# Image rotated when saved

Tags: c#, uwp, sharpdx

I have problem. I have my UWP app to capture photo. I capture it, save it, then load it and write text into. The problem is that I capture and save photo in portrait orientation but when I load it the photo is in landscape orientation. Are there any properties to set when saving picture to prevent this behavior? I thought the orientation problem is caused by loading method but when I posted my question on msdn forum with illustrating picture it rotated to landscape as well.

One important thing to mention: I tried to save picture with flipped landscape orientation but output was in normal landscape...

This is my saving method:

```
private static async Task ReencodeAndSavePhotoAsync(IRandomAccessStream stream, StorageFile file, PhotoOrientation photoOrientation)
    {
        using (var inputStream = stream)
        {
            var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(inputStream);

            using (var outputStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
            {
                var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateForTranscodingAsync(outputStream, decoder);

                var properties = new BitmapPropertySet { { "System.Photo.Orientation", new BitmapTypedValue(photoOrientation, Windows.Foundation.PropertyType.UInt16) } };

                await encoder.BitmapProperties.SetPropertiesAsync(properties);
                await encoder.FlushAsync();
            }
        }
    }
```

And method to get photo orientation:

```
private static PhotoOrientation ConvertOrientationToPhotoOrientation(SimpleOrientation orientation)
    {
        switch (orientation)
        {
            case SimpleOrientation.Rotated90DegreesCounterclockwise:
                return PhotoOrientation.Rotate90;
            case SimpleOrientation.Rotated180DegreesCounterclockwise:
                return PhotoOrientation.Rotate180;
            case SimpleOrientation.Rotated270DegreesCounterclockwise:
                return PhotoOrientation.Rotate270;
            case SimpleOrientation.NotRotated:
            default:
                return PhotoOrientation.Normal;
        }
    }
```

SOLVED: The problem is in case you use the program which dont care about metadata. I opened the picture in my own program and red just bitmap, not metadata with information about preview rotation, but just default position of pixels. I had to rotate BitmapEncoder:

```
encoder.BitmapTransform.Rotation = BitmapRotation.Clockwise90Degrees;
```

I hope this will help someone

Comment: Use a `Image` and flip it instead of the bitmap properties thing

Comment: those properties should set metadata to right orientation. I need to rotate and save file and I didnt find any way to do that with image...

Comment: Just create an Image object from the Bitmap (or use `Image.FromStream()`), rotate it with `Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType)` and create a Bitmap from that Image. Well maybe on upw you can't do that, on windows `Image` comes from `System.Drawing`

Comment: I already solved it in encoder, but thanks. You gave me the right idea